# After update of Firefox 4.0, add-on buttons vanished

Tags: firefox, browser-addons

After I updated to Firefox 4.0b7, the buttons for all add-ons vanished. They are no longer visible in the toolbar nor in the "Add-on bar".

How can I get my buttons back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to uninstall FireFox and re-install it again then add the addons one by one maybe that fixes the problem.

Note: Firefox 4 is Still beta which is made for Software Testers and not Normal Users, so dont expect it to be ready for daily use until they release the Final Version.

If You're using Firefox daily like Me then I would Suggest that you Install a Stable Release and wait until Firefox 4 Becomes Stable.

Comment: I created a new profile with `-ProfileManager`. After installing the add-ons again in the new profile, FF behaves as it should.

Answer (score 1):

Right click the menu bar select customize.  A window now opens.  Check whether the buttons you expected found there.  If it does just drag and place it to the desired place.

Comment: Nope, they aren't there.

Answer (score 0):

Are your add-ons compatible with Firefox 4? If not, they will be inactivated, and you'll have to try and find updated versions of them to reactivate. Go to Tools -> Add-ons to check which ones are installed. I presume you'll be able to see which are inactivated from there too, but I don't have any so I'm not 100% certain.

Comment: Some of them are. For example "NoScript".

Comment: @Aaron Digulla: Then I'm out of ideas, sorry. Hope you get better answers!